# Includes check with inline array creation in Angular component.html does not compile

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this `enum`:

```
export enum Status {
    SOME_VAL = "SOME_VAL",
    SOME_VAL_2 = "SOME_VAL_2",
    SOME_VAL_3 = "SOME_VAL_3";
}
```

and my `interface`:

```
export SomeInterface {
    status?: Status;
}
```

and a simple use of `includes` method with in-line array creation in `some.component.ts`:

```
let someVal: boolean = [Status.SOME_VAL, Status.SOME_VAL_2].includes(this.someObject.status);
```

works as expected. However, within the `some.component.html`:

```
<div *ngIf="[Status.SOME_VAL, Status.SOME_VAL_2].includes(someObject.status)">
    ...
</div>
```

gives this warning:

```
Argument type Status is not assignable to parameter type Status.SOME_VAL | Status.SOME_VAL_2
```

and doesn't compile. Converting to:

```
<div *ngIf="$any([Status.SOME_VAL, Status.SOME_VAL_2]).includes(someObject.status)">
    ...
</div>
```

gets rid of the warning, since I believe erases the method's signature, and does make the code compile, but does not work as expected, always evaluates to `false` without error or warning (possibly resulting in an error of which the logs I cannot see). How do I overcome this?

**Update:**

I do have:

```
Status = Status;
```

in my `some.component.ts`, so that I can reference it from `html`.

Comment: There are some problems you might run into. E.g. `status?: Status` is of type `Status | undefined`, so you already get an error in `let someVal: boolean = ...`. Also, how do you assign `someObject.status`? Should be like e.g. `status: Status.SOME_Val`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created an `AsPipe`:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'as'
})
export class AsPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform<T>(value: any, args: T): T {
    return value as T;
  }
}
```

and use it as follows in the template:

```
*ngIf="([Status.SOME_VAL, Status.SOME_VAL_2] | as: [Status]).includes(someObject.status)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the enum instance to do that. To do that, declare a variable in .ts that holds enum reference and can be used in the.html template. For example:

In ts:

```
public status = Status;
```

In html:

```
<div *ngIf="[status.SOME_VAL, status.SOME_VAL_2].includes(someObject.status)">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: I do have that.

Comment: Then its about your `someObject.status`. It's value cannot be converted to Status enum's items. Can you verify this?

Comment: I've updated the question, they are the same. If they weren't, `let someVal: boolean = [Status.SOME_VAL, Status.SOME_VAL_2].includes(this.someObject.status);` wouldn't work in `ts`.

Comment: Hmm.. it should work. I use [].indexOf() in my html template and it works fine.

Comment: Well u can create another variable in .ts and give it the array `someVal: Status[] = [...]` Then `*ngIf="someVal.includes(someObject.status)"` because in my knowledge this error should not come.

Comment: I know I could create variables in `ts` and control the visibility in `html` with those. But that'd be impractical, because I have quite a few of them in the template. So, I'm not looking for a workaround.

Comment: Using a 'static' property is preferable though since calling functions in a template check (or value calculation) is more expensive since it will be not called only once, but every update cycle.